# Expectation of truncated normal distributed random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, bivariate

Consider $X=X_r+jX_i$  to be a circularly symmetric Gaussian random variable, and $$X\sim\mathcal{N}_c(0,\sigma^2)$$ where $\mathcal{N_c}$ denotes the Gaussian distribution for complex random variable. Here $X_r$ and $X_i$ are the real and the imaginary parts of $X$. Due to circularly symmetry assumption (used in the signal processing and digital communications literature), zero mean random variables $X_r$ and $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d) with each $$X_r\sim\mathcal{N_r}(0,\sigma^2/2)$$ $$X_i\sim\mathcal{N_r}(0,\sigma^2/2)$$ where $\mathcal{N_r}$ denotes the Gaussian distribution for real random variable. Now from the same random process we have two variables $X_1=X(t)$ and $X_2=X(t+\tau)$. Thus the correlation coefficient is given as

$$\rho(\tau) = \frac{E[X(t)X^*(t+\tau)]}{E[X(t)X^*(t)]}$$

For present case,  $\rho(\pm T)= \rho_1(constant)$.

It is clear that $E[X(t)X^*(t)]=\sigma^2$ and $E[X(t)X^*(t+T)]=\rho_1\sigma^2$

Now, I need to calculate $$\mathbb{E}[XX^*(t+T)||X|<a,|X(t+T)|<a]$$

$$\mathbb{E}[|XX^*(t+T)|^2||X|<a,|X(t+T)|<a]$$ $$\mathbb{E}[|XX^*(t+T)|^4||X|<a,|X^(t+T)|<a]$$

where $a$ is a constant and $X^*$ is complex conjugate of $X$.

> I know some steps to simplify if $X$ and $Y$ are real random varibales $$\mathbb{E}[XY\mid X<a,Y<a]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[XY1_{X<a,Y<a}]}{P(X<a,Y<a)}$$ Let us define U and V two independent standard normal random variables we can write $$X=\sigma U$$ $$Y=\sigma\left(\rho U+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}V\right)$$ Replacing them into $\mathbb{E}[XY\mid X<a,Y<a]$ $$P(X<a,Y<a)=P\left(U<\frac{a}{\sigma},\rho U+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}V<\frac{a}{\sigma} \right)$$ $$\mathbb{E}[XY1_{X<a,Y<a}]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sigma^2\left(\rho U^2+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}UV\right)1_{U<\frac{a}{\sigma},\rho U+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}V<\frac{a}{\sigma}}\right]$$

Comment: So X is the real part and Y is the imaginary part of the complex normal?  How does truncation enter the problem,

Comment: @MichaelChernick They both are complex.

Comment: You can't talk about complex normal random variables $X$ and $Y$ with just the mean and covariance matrix; you also need to specify the _relation matrix_ (see, e.g. [the Wikipedia entry on complex normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution)). It seems as if you are thinking about the circularly symmetric complex normal random variables used in the signal processing and digital communications literature, and if this is so, you need to say so explicitly. -1 pending a more detailed definition from you.

Comment: Hi. I have redefined my question. I hope now it make sense.